# Data Driven test not passing 1 parameter

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

## 1. My Page Model for Login Page:

```
import {Selector,t} from "testcafe"
class LoginPage{
    constructor(){
        this.email= Selector("#email")
        this.password= Selector("#password")
        this.loginButton =Selector(".new-button")
        this.link= Selector("a").withText("Welcome, System Administrator")
        this.onscreenmessage = Selector("#main > div.notification.notification-error > div > p")

    }

async login(username, password){
    var that = this;
    await t.typeText(that.email, username)
           .typeText(that.password, password)
           .pressKey("enter")  
           .expect(this.link).ok()
    console.log("User is able to login successfully")   
}
```

}

```
export default LoginPage
```

## 2. My Data set for login

```
[
    {
        "testcasename:": "Test for Non Existing User by username",
        "loginusername": "TestUser",
        "loginpassword": "I love TestCafe!",
        "onscreenmessage": "Invalid Login or password."
    },
    {
        "testcasename:": "Test for Non Existing User by email",
        "loginusername": "OliviaPeyton@abc.com",
        "loginpassword": "TestCafe is awesome!",
        "onscreenmessage": "Invalid Login or password."
    },
    {
        "testcasename:": "Test for Valid User and invalid password",
        "loginusername": "Demopreview_admin",
        "loginpassword": "TestCafe is awesome!",
        "onscreenmessage": "Invalid username/email or password."
    }
]
```

## 3. Here is how my Tests are written - basically iterating through json file and am expecting to see the testcase name show up in the logs. But get it as undefined.

```
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';
import {login} from "../helper"
import LoginPage  from "../page-object/Login-Page"

const dataSet = require('../test/testdata/login.json')

fixture `Role based access control`
    .page `https://demopreview-qa-test-myplace.net/users/sign_in`

const LoginPage = new LoginPage()

dataSet.forEach(userdata => {
test('Executing Tests '${data.testcasename'}', async t => {
        await LoginPage.login(userdata.loginusername,userdata.loginpassword);
        await t.expect(LoginPage.onscreenmessage.textContent).eql(userdata.onscreenmessage,'Match not found');
    });
});
```

Looking for a pair of eyes to scan and see what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two typos in your code:

- `testcasename:` instead of `testcasename` (extra colon) in your `.json` file.
- incorrect variable name in the following code: `test('Executing Tests '${data.testcasename'}'...`. `data` instead of `userdata`

Comment: duh! how silly of me. the 2nd one you highlighted was something i caused when pasting the code here as I had to remove some company specific names when posting in a public forum. So I had already fixed that in my code. Truly that ':' is what that eluded me. Thank you so much for being my 2nd pair of eyes Alex.